# In Javapoet, why "ClassName.bestGuess("int")" get error?

Tags: android, apt, javapoet

Is there a way to resolve the code? -

```
for (FieldInfo fieldInfo : info.getResult()) {
    result.addField(FieldSpec.builder(ClassName.bestGuess(fieldInfo.getClazz()),fieldInfo.getName())
          .addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE)
          .build()
    );
}
```

when `fieldInfo.getClazz()` returns "int","float", the code would throw an error as

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for int

Comment: Can you share what `info` here is and confirm the `FieldInfo` is `sun.reflect.FieldInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

Java’s type system has lots of kinds of types: classes, arrays, primitives, parameterized types, etc. The method you’re using assumes the caller wants a `ClassName` and not a primitive. Use `TypeName.INT` for that.